# What are tin whiskers and what causes them?

Tags: pcb, soldering

I can imagine what they might be, but how and where do they form and what causes them?

Comment: There is some recent research that offers a possible mechanism to explain this. See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25228767 And an interesting video that talks about the research http://tedxtalks.ted.com/video/Liquid-Metal-The-Prophecy-of-th;search%3Atag%3A%22tedxncssm%22

Answer (score 10):

> Tin whiskers are filamentary growths that spontaneously grow 
>   from electroplated tin surfaces.

[image] (from [NASA article](http://nepp.nasa.gov/whisker/background/index.htm))

> The exact cause of tin whisker growth is still not fully understood.
>   It is known that a whisker grows from its base and that the tin around
>   the base does not thin as the whisker grows. It seems that the energy
>   for growth comes from microstrains present in the tin or from
>   externally applied pressure. Tin atoms appear to diffuse along screw
>   dislocations within the tin and are pushed outwards by stresses.
>   Growth rate varies tremendously, and it may be unsteady. Whiskers can
>   fully develop in minutes or take decades to form. Spurts of growth may
>   occur [1986].

Overview article: [A History of Tin Whisker Theory: 1946 to 2004](http://thor.inemi.org/webdownload/newsroom/Presentations/SMTAI-04_tin_whiskers.pdf)

There's more of references to in-depth information on whiskering [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisker_%28metallurgy%29#References).  But, it seems that most of publications focus on prevention than on the formation mechanism.

**update, related article:**
Root Cause Failure Analysis of Dendrite Shorting: A Comparison
of Analytical Techniques
[Printed Circuit Design and Fab magazine](http://pcdandf.com/pcdesign/) [it's a free-of-charge industry rag]
Dec 2014 issue, pp.28-34
([PDF](http://upmediagroup.com/publications/1412PCDFCA.pdf) or [interactive viewer](http://ourdigitalmags.com/publication/?i=235513&p=30))

Comment: The original question also asked for what a tim whisker was.  added in a quote from the paper you referenced.  Nice reference BTW.